# Jenkins exclude branch in some GitHub organization repos but not all

Tags: git, github, jenkins

We have a Github Organization defined in Jenkins configured to build branches master and develop.  There are some repos in our org that do not want the develop branch to build because they are built on a different Jenkins server.  Is it possible to exclude the develop branch only on specific repos within the GitHub org but allow them in others?

Answer (score 1):

You could split your current Jenkins job in two:

- one triggers on a push in any of your GitHub organization repo: it would check which repo and which branch is concerned
- one doing the actual build

If the first job determines it is a valid branch for a valid repo, it would call the second one (using **[pipelines](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/)** here would be a good fit to [chain jobs](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/06/29/from-freestyle-to-pipeline/))

Answer (score 0):

You can choose "Inverse" strategy for targeting branches to build.

Check out Jenkins job configuration,

"Source Code Management" section (choose "Git")
Additional Behaviours
click "Add" button
choose "Strategy for choosing what to build"
select "Inverse" strategy in combo box.
(Don't forget to fill in "Branches to build" text field by "master")